# How to set the color of the counter on a TextInputLayout?

Tags: android, android-design-library

I'm using a TextInputLayout wrapped around an EditText.  Right now the counter is black, I'd like it to be white.  I'm not sure what option to set to get it to be white.

```
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:counterEnabled="true"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textColorHint="@color/white"
        >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/myfield"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
            android:hint="@string/myfield_hint"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:maxLength="26"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textColorHint="@color/white"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please add:

```
app:counterTextAppearance="@android:color/white"
```

to your TextInputLayout.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Actually "counterTextAppearance" property not receive a color, but style. So create style like: "<style name="TextLabel" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat"><item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item></style>" and then set property of TextInputLayout: "app:counterTextAppearance="@style/TextLabel"

Comment: Thanks Tayna Bonaldo. Your comment did help. Its actually style and not color.

Comment: @TaynãBonaldo this should be an answer! :)

Comment: @TaynãBonaldo but the parent should be `TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small`, as stated [here](http://www.materialdoc.com/character-counter/).

Comment: why this answer marked as correct??
Sufian's link more helpful.

Comment: can you change the color of `counterTextAppearance` when it's activated?

Answer (score 17):

I decided to write this answer based on comments from previous one.

At first, you need to create the style for your counter, for example:

```
<style name="CounterStyle" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <!--other parameters that you want to change -->
</style>
```

Then add this style to TextInputLayout:

```
app:counterTextAppearance="@style/CounterStyle"
```

That's all, it should works. Full code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:counterEnabled="true"
        app:counterTextAppearance="@style/CounterStyle"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textColorHint="@color/white">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/myfield"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
            android:hint="@string/myfield_hint"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:maxLength="26"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textColorHint="@color/white"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

You can also use some style for the overflow counter:

```
app:counterOverflowTextAppearance="@style/YourOverflowTextStyleHere"
```

As described [here](http://www.materialdoc.com/character-counter/) (thanks @Sufian for the link)

Comment: Is there a way to change the counter's color when the text input is in focus?

Comment: Idk, but I suppose that you can use View.OnFocusChangeListener on EditText to detect focus, and then try to change TextInputLayout's style programmatically. Another way to try to extend TextInputLayout with requested functionality. But I think this way is more complicated.