# Changing the color of TextInputLayout's Counter

Tags: android, material-design, material-components-android, android-textinputlayout, android-textinputedittext

I'm trying to change the color of TextInputLayout's counter

I've tried the accepted answers but they do not work.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33880925/11110509

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/til_custom_msg"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:hint="Message"
        app:counterEnabled="true"
        app:counterMaxLength="300"
    
        //Accepted answer one
        app:counterTextAppearance="@android:color/white">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/et_custom_msg"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Accepted answer two:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41257235/11110509

```
<style name="CounterStyle" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <!--other parameters that you want to change -->
</style>
```

`app:counterTextAppearance="@style/CounterStyle"`

The issue maybe because my TextInputLayout uses the material version

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
```

and theirs uses the support

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
```

If so, how can I do it with the Material one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use

```
'app:counterTextColor="YOUR_PREFERRED_COLOR"'
```

Resource: [CounterTextColor](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/textfield/TextInputLayout#attr_TextInputLayout_counterTextColor)